# Racket Scheme: Include externel rkt file with dynamic file name

Tags: include, scheme, racket

I want to load external rkt file in racket scheme from a parameter of a function.
E.G.,

```
(define (test fileName)
   (include fileName)
)
```

However, I am getting error indicating that fileName is not a pathname string, `file' form, or`lib' form.

Is there a way to fix this or is there another better way to include a file from dynamic filename?

Comment: The following section of the docs might help you reconcile what you want with what Racket offers: http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/load.html. Sam's recommendation (`dynamic-require`) is also good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is to make the external file a module, and use [`dynamic-require`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Module_Names_and_Loading.html?q=dynamic-require#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._dynamic-require%29%29).

Comment: Is it possible to provide a simple example? I was trying to get it working but failed. dynamic-require didnt give me any errors but I couldn't access the definitions.

Comment: See the bottom of: http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/mk-namespace.html for an example that uses `dynamic-require`.